# Change the default message "Validation Error: Value is required" to just "Value is required"

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

Can I modify this default `required="true"` validation message to show only "Value is required"?

> formId:inputId: Validation Error: Value is required.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Either* use the input component's `requiredMessage` attribute:

```
<x:inputXxx ... required="true" requiredMessage="Value is required" />
```

*Or* create a properties file in the classpath which contains the custom message template:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = Value is required.
```

and is been registered as message bundle in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<application>
    <message-bundle>com.example.CustomMessages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

The above example assumes that the file name is `CustomMessages.properties` and is been placed in `com.example` package. You can name and place it wherever you want.

You can find an overview of all message keys in chapter 2.5.2.4 of [the JSF specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html), such as `javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED_detail` in case you're using them.

Comment: Hi BalusC, i check that both http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ and http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-full-oth-JSpec/ are the same (EVAL vs IMPL), could there be a mistake?

Comment: No. Some APIs have separate docs for this. Endusers (read: us, developers) should just read the "Evaluation" spec. Implementors (like Mojarra and MyFaces do) should read the "Implementation" spec. But for JSF spec it's indeed not different.

Comment: Hi BalusC, can i actually override Apache Common Validator's message this way too? http://myfaces.apache.org/commons12/myfaces-validators12/tagdoc.html

Comment: @BalusC Can I internationalize this custom messages? I put the javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED in my internationalized JSF properties but it doesn't show this message but the default message (Design: Validation Error: Value is required.)

Comment: @BalusC I am getting well all my internationalized messsages except the overriden JSF messages. Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: I tried this approach, but it does not really work for me. I am reading the message from a message bundle and although it retrieves the message from the bundle, it still shows the IDs on the message.This is how the message is shown: myForm:j_idt76: Überprüfungsfehler: Wert ist erforderlich. I do not want to add a requiredMessage attribute to all my inputFields. Also note, that my input field is a p:inputField . I could only solve this, once i added a label attribute in my inputField

Comment: I add that you can also customize, if you use, the details, using `javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED_detail`

Answer (score 1):

I think i got it here.

Added label:

```
<p:inputText id="hotelName" value="#{editHotelBackingBean.hotel.name}" required="true" label="#{labelResource.hotelName}">
```

Now it looks like this:

> Hotel Name: Validation Error: Value is required.