# Getting the component id on the error validation message

Tags: validation, jsf

I've tried this piece of code for submetting a date of birth field on a form :

```
<h:form>
    <h2>JSF Registration App</h2>
    <h4>Registration Form</h4>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td>
        <h:inputText label="First Name" id="fname" value="#{mybean.firstName}" required="true" />
                <h:message for="fname" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{userBean.dob}" id="dob" required="true" > 
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM-dd-yy"/> 
                </h:inputText> (mm-dd-yy) 
                <h:message for="dob"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <p>
        <h:commandButton value="clique ici pour valider" action="Register" />
    </p>

</h:form>
```

I got this message after leaving the field empty

```
(mm-dd-yy) j_idt5:dob : erreur de validation. Vous devez indiquer une valeur.
```

why there is the jsf automatically generated id " j_idt5:dob" within the message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input component's client ID becomes the default conversion/validation message label as long as you don't explicitly specify the `label` attribute of the input component like so:

```
<h:inputText ... label="Date of birth" />
```

If you do it, then the message will become:

> Date of birth : erreur de validation. Vous devez indiquer une valeur.

---

The `j_idt5` in the client ID is coming from `<h:form>`. If you give it a fixed ID like `id="register"` (and keep the `label` of the input component omitted), then the message becomes:

> register:dob : erreur de validation. Vous devez indiquer une valeur.

---

If necessary, you override the whole validator message by `validatorMessage` attribute.

```
<h:inputText ... validatorMessage="Please enter date of birth." />
```

> Please enter date of birth.

---

Equivalently, the conversion error message from `<f:convertDateTime>` is overridable by `converterMessage` attribute.

```
<h:inputText ... converterMessage="Please enter date of birth in mm-dd-yy format." />
```

> Please enter date of birth in mm-dd-yy format.